# C++ Windows form application Switching between forms

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

So i have my main form and i open a second form using this code
`this->Hide();
Form2^ dlg=gcnew Form2();
dlg->ShowDialog();`
how do i go back from the second form to the main one?

Comment: This question is **not** related to C++, since it is about C++/CLI.

Comment: That is a pretty bad idea, a dialog must always have an owner window.  One of the more obvious failure-modes is for the dialog to get covered by another window and no way for the user to easily find it back again.  What you are *asking* about is the FormClosing event, available to call this->Show().  Note how FormClosed is too late.  Avoid pursuing bad ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In the dialog code set the DialogResult property, this will close the dialog and return to the main form, ShowDialog will return the DialogResult value you set.

Alternatively you can have a button on the dialog that has a DialogResult property set and then clicking the button will close the dialog and return the value associated with the button.